# Как называется алгоритм, по поиску минимального количества групп содержащих элементы из списка?

Tags: алгоритм, терминология

Как называется алгоритмеческая задачка, где у нас есть список нужных нам предметов (допустим: А,Б,В,К,Л,М), а у контрагента - набор комплектов предметов (допустим: АБЖ, ВКО, ВЛМ, АМН, К) с ценами за комплект, и нам нужно найти самый дешевый набор комплектов который даст нам все нужные предметы? Дубли или лишние предметы не важны. Главное - получение предметов по нашему списку и минимизация цены.

Нужно именно название алгоритма, т.к. проблема наверняка давно известная и имеет оптимальные решения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В процессе формулирования текста вопроса, всплыли определенные термины и по ним удалось найти название задачи в Википедии:

[Задача о покрытии множества](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) ([Set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem))

При включении в расчет цен, задача превращается в "Weighted set cover problem".

*Подходы к решению этой задачи также доступны в вики, но это уже тема для отдельного вопроса*